Can the French government transfer fighter jets to Ukraine without some explicit parliamentary approval, or was that given already?
In June Macron announced France will be transferring Mirage 2000 jets to Ukraine, and he even gave a time frame of around 6 months for that to happen. But the French parliament still seems deadlocked on forming a new government etc.
So, can Macron transfer jets to Ukraine without some explicit parliamentary approval, or did that happen already?

FWTW, the current/outgoing PM set a "reversible budget" https://www.lemonde.fr/en/politics/article/2024/08/21/france-s-outgoing-prime-minister-proposes-spending-freeze-in-2025_6719235_5.html I'm not sure how that 'reversible' part would work for any foreign aid though: ask for it back after giving it out?

Is there reason to assume he would need explicit parliamentary approval? How was it in the past when France transferred other equipment to Ukraine?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: if he doesn't that's an/the answer. I'd assume that like in most democracies foreign aid is in some way reflected in the French gov't budget, but I could be wrong, especially how detailed that needs to be.

The French parliament is not deadlocked, it is fully functionning since July. It is the government that is deadlocked, with the current gov having officially resigned but President Macron unwilling to name a new one because he's unhappy with the elections' result.

A Mirage 2000 may be up to 40 years old. There was a minor flap over EU funding and Ukraine aid when some countries wanted reimbursement for old weapons at original purchase price, others wanted the replacement price, and yet others valued it at zero because it was already depreciated in their accounts.

@o.m.: there's still a market for them https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2024/04/362057/france-approves-transfer-of-30-mirage-2009-e-fighter-jets-from-uae-to-morocco. Reportedly France will send the 2000-5 model, which isn't that old. F-16 is 50 years old by first flight.

@o.m.: and guess what they used against the Houthis https://www.key.aero/article/mirage-2000-5f-pilots-score-first-post-ww2-aerial-victories-france The real issue seems to be that they might not have the aircraft to spare https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2024/06/13/war-in-ukraine-can-france-s-mirage-2000-5-jets-help-the-ukrainian-army_6674732_4.html

@Evargalo: AFAICT besides electing their leadership [incl. those of various committees] they didn't do anything else this session.  True, they're probably on vacation.

@Evargalo: and even in that nobody had a majority https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/dyn/actualites-accueil-hub/yael-braun-pivet-elue-presidente-de-l-assemblee-nationale3 They managed to elect someone because of the special rules that turn it into a FTPT in round 3. They can't pass laws like that though.

This is two different questions: (1) a question about what the law is; and (2) a question about what the French Parliament has approved.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I meant that it is fully functionning according to its own rules (there's a small caveat about ministers voting as deputies, the legally of which has been vividly debatted). And sure, the Parliament can pass laws even without a global majority: 60 laws have been voted between 2022 and 2024 (and most of them without consitutionnal tricks like article 49.3 that can only be triggered by the government) while there was no majority in the National Assembly.

@Evargalo: I'm not excluding they could agree on some matters, like e.g. [in the US] even the GOP dominated House eventually managed to pass that last package for Ukraine [after months of deadlock through]. Just seems less likely there will be fast agreement like when there's a majority supporting a government [be it a coalition].

France and Ukraine signed a defense agreement in February 2024, and it was approved by the French parliament in March. Technically, the government didn't need formal parliament approval (unlike when directly sending troops) but, to get democratic legitimacy on the issue, they chose to consult the Parliament as per article 50-1 of the Constitution. So from a legal point of view, everything is on track.
From a financial perspective, Macron announced that the fighter jets and the associated training can already be financed with 2024 army funds. In theory, a  military programme for the 2024-2030 period including Ukraine support was also established by a 2023 bill. That's the big plan, but in terms of operational financial details, a question mark remains for 2025 and beyond. Y+1 budget is usually voted around Q4 of year Y and without a government or a clear majority in the Parliament this time, there are fears of a budgetary deadlock (although France has mechanisms to avoid shutdowns like in the US). The vote on the nation's budget could be delayed, causing Ukraine equipment funding to run out, and the composition of the military budget could be more contested than in the previous term where the president's party had a stronger position in the parliament.
If I could hazard a guess based on what happened previously though, defense and Ukraine support is a more consensual topic than others and a majority of MPs could potentially agree on an extraordinary bill to unlock funds if the situation required it.
